# Laravel Scout toSearchableArray attribute is not filterable

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-scout

I've been doing some testing with laravel scout and according to the documentation (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scout#configuring-searchable-data), I've mapped my User model as such:

```
 /**
     * Get the indexable data array for the model.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function toSearchableArray()
    {
        $data = $this->toArray();
        return array_merge($data, [
            'entity' => 'An entity'
        ]);
    }
```

Just for the sake of testing, this is literally what I came down to on the debugging.

After importing the User model with this mapping, I can see on the meilisearch dashboard it is indeed showing the user data + the entity = 'An entity'.

However, when applying this:

`User::search('something')->where('entity', 'An entity')->get()`
It produces the following error:

```
"message": " --> 1:1\n  |\n1 | entity=\"An entity\"\n  | ^----^\n  |\n  = attribute `entity` is not filterable, available filterable attributes are: ",
"exception": "MeiliSearch\\Exceptions\\ApiException",
"file": "/var/www/api/vendor/meilisearch/meilisearch-php/src/Http/Client.php",
```

Tracing back to view the 'filterable attributes', I've ended at the conclusion that:

```
$client = app(\MeiliSearch\Client::class);
dump($client->index('users')->getFilterableAttributes()); // Returns []
$client->index('users')->updateFilterableAttributes(['entity']);
dump($client->index('users')->getFilterableAttributes()); // Returns ['entity']
```

Forcing the updateFilterableAttributes now allows me to complete the search as intended, but I don't feel this should be the regular behaviour? If its mapped on the searchableArray, it should be searchable? What am I not understanding and what other approaches are there to achieve this goal?

Comment: Ever found what was the issue?

Answer (score 1):

This is actually not an issue but a requirement of meilisearch in particular. Scout under the hood uses different drivers for indexing - "algolia", "meilisearch", "database", "collection" and even "null", all of them have different indexing methods unifing of which would be troublesome and inefficient for scout I believe.

So filtering or a faceted search, as meilisearch refers to it, requires us to establish filtering criteria first, which is empty by default for document (models in laravel) fields.

Quoting from the docs:

> **This step is mandatory and cannot be done at search time.** Filters need
> to be properly processed and prepared by Meilisearch before they can
> be used.
>
> Updating **filterableAttributes** requires recreating the entire
> index. This may take a significant amount of time depending on your
> dataset size.

For more info please refer to meilisearch official docs https://docs.meilisearch.com/learn/advanced/filtering_and_faceted_search.html